# Python 2.7: How to convert unicode escapes in a string into actual utf-8 characters

Tags: python, string, utf-8, converters, unicode-escapes

I use python 2.7 and I'm receiving a **string** from a server (not in unicode!).
Inside that string I find text with unicode escape sequences. For example like this:

```
<a href = "http://www.mypage.com/\u0441andmoretext">\u00b2<\a>
```

How do I convert those `\uxxxx` - back to utf-8? The answers I found were either dealing with `&#` or required `eval()` which is too slow for my purposes. I need a universal solution for any text containing such sequenes.

*Edit:*
`<\a>` is a typo but I want a tolerance against such typos as well. There should only be reaction to `\u`

The example text is meant in proper python syntax like this:

```
"<a href = \"http://www.mypage.com/\\u0441andmoretext\">\\u00b2<\\a>"
```

The desired output is in proper python syntax

```
"<a href = \"http://www.mypage.com/\xd1\x81andmoretext\">\xc2\xb2<\\a>"
```

Comment: have you tried `str.encode('utf-8')`? That converts a string into unicode.

Comment: `<\a>` isn't valid HTML either...

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: In what encoding are you receiving the string from the external source?

Comment: The fact that your string contains `\a` and not `\\a` strongly suggests this is not possible - how can you distinguish _"I want the character entity described by `\u0441`"_ from _"I want the sequence of 6 characters `\u0441`"_

Comment: I think `<\a>` is a typo

Comment: Is this the string you want... `'<a href = "http://www.mypage.com/\xd1\x81andmoretext">\xc2\xb2</a>'`

Comment: yes `<\a>` is a typo, but I want to be tolerant to such typos. And yes I want the string Shashank mentions. @Eric: I can't distinguish those cases but I want it always converted by default whenever there is a substring like that. `\\u0441` (I mean `\\\u0441` in proper python syntax) should be converted to `\\xd1` (by which I mean `\\\xd1` in proper python syntax)

Comment: Now I'm getting confused with those slashes. and I meant \xd1\x81 of course... I updated the question

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
>>> s = "<a href = \"http://www.mypage.com/\\u0441andmoretext\">\\u00b2<\\a>"
>>> s.decode("raw_unicode_escape")
u'<a href = "http://www.mypage.com/\u0441andmoretext">\xb2<\\a>'
```

And then you can encode to utf8 as usual.

Comment: Seems more like what I was looking for. For some reason it still doesn't convert the \\u0441 (as it didn't for you)

Answer (score 2):

Python does contain some special string codecs for cases like this.

In this case, if there are no other characters outside the 32-127 range, you can safely decode your byte-string using the "unicode_escape" codec to have a proper Unicode text object in Python. 
(On which your program should be performing all textual operations) - 
Whenever you are outputting that text again, you convert it to utf-8 as usual:

```
rawtext = r"""<a href="http://www.mypage.com/\u0441andmoretext">\u00b2<\a>"""
text = rawtext.decode("unicode_escape")
# Text operations go here
...
output_text = text.encode("utf-8")
```

If there are othe bytes outside the 32-127 range, the unicode_escape codec 
assumes them to be in the latin1 encoding. So if your response mixes utf-8 and these \uXXXX sequences you have to:

1. decode the original string using utf-8
2. encode back to latin1
3. decode using "unicode_escape"
4. work on the text
5. encode back to utf-8

Comment: This converts the `"\\a"` too, and I think the OP wanted it to remain as it is. I get `text = u'<a href = "http://www.mypage.com/\u0441andmoretext">\xb2<\x07>'`

Comment: Which is so bad news to the OP - that means the only workable solution will be a regexp -substitution parsing.