# Decoding Python Unicode strings that contain double blackslashes

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

My strings look like this `\\xec\\x88\\x98`, but if I print them they look like this `\xec\x88\x98`, and when I decode them they look like this `\xec\x88\x98`

If I type the string in manually as `\xec\x88\x98` and then decode it, I get the value I want `수`.

If I `x.decode('unicode-escape')` it removes the double slashes, but when decoding the value returned by `x.decode('unicode-escape')`, the value I get is `ì`.

How would I go about decoding the original `\\xec\\x88\\x98`, so that I get the value correct output?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805425/python-2-7-how-to-convert-unicode-escapes-in-a-string-into-actual-utf-8-charact) seems like it might be useful.

Comment: You should _always_ tag Unicode questions with the Python version you're using because Unicode handling in Python 2 is quite different to how it works in Python 3.

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3? Showing escaped strings can be confusing... can you show us the `repr` of the string (what you'd type into python to get the string)? A good way to do that is `print(repr(x))` and then post the quotes and everything.

Comment: @PM2Ring I've updated the tags, thx

Comment: @tdelaney `'\\xec\\x88\\x98'` is what I get

Comment: @tdelaney also, I wrote a web spider and the text is pulled from Korean news sites

Comment: It sounds like you did something wrong to get these strings in the first place. Maybe an extra `str` call somewhere or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2 you can use the ['string-escape' codec](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) to convert `'\\xec\\x88\\x98'` to `'\xec\x88\x98'`, which is the UTF-8 encoding of `u'\uc218'`.

Here's a short demo. Unfortunately, my terminal's font doesn't have that character so I can't print it. So instead I'll print its name and it's representation, and I'll also convert it to a Unicode-escape sequence.

```
import unicodedata as ud

src = '\\xec\\x88\\x98'
print repr(src)

s = src.decode('string-escape')
print repr(s)

u = s.decode('utf8')
print ud.name(u)
print repr(u), u.encode('unicode-escape')
```

**output**

```
'\\xec\\x88\\x98'
'\xec\x88\x98'
HANGUL SYLLABLE SU
u'\uc218' \uc218
```

However, this is a "band-aid" solution. You should try to fix this problem upstream (in your Web spider) so that you receive the data as plain UTF-8 instead of that string-escaped UTF-8 that you're currently getting.

Comment: `'string-escape'` seems to have solved my problems. Also, thanks for the tip!